# Where can I find SPAD-T?

Tags: software, resource-request

I am looking for an old program called SPAD-T that is still used for textual analysis. Can anybody tell me where to find it? Otherwise can anybody send me a copy of the software? It shouldn't be copyrighted.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't mean [SPADE](http://www.isi.edu/licensed-sw/spade/) do you?

Comment: "It shouldn't be copyrighted." That seems unlikely.

Comment: May be on a linguistics forum I should have written "abandonware" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abandonware

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut I guess not. The software I'm looking for was developed by a French company... In French...

Comment: Cross posted here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8143/is-the-spad-t-textual-analysis-software-still-available

Comment: Also answered here: http://cogsci.stackexchange.com/questions/8143/is-the-spad-t-textual-analysis-software-still-available

Answer (score 1):

A bit late as a response - I've just stumbled on this. But I believe SPAD-T was released as the open-source DTM-VIC available here http://www.dtmvic.com/05_SoftwareE.html (10 April 2016)